# Exchange symmetry question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles

I am trying to learn Quantum mechanics using [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HTZF.png).

I have a question regarding exchange symmetry Sec 10.1 , page 214 (Image added below).

My question is why is $\delta$ in equation 10.3 not a function of $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},t$ ?

To give a crude example,  if one assumes

$$\psi(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},t) = \left(\left\lVert\mathbf{a}\right\rVert_2+\left\lVert\mathbf{b}\right\rVert_2\right)e^{j\left\lVert\mathbf{a}\right\rVert_2*t}  $$

Then equation 10.2 is satisfied but neither 10.5 nor 10.6 is satisfied.

I am guessing we are using some property from Schrödinger's equation to argue that $\delta$ is independent of $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},t$.

Can someone please explain what I am missing?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HTZF.png) Philips A.C., Introduction to Quantum Mechanics

[image: Screenshot of page 214]

Comment: @Mauricio I think if one assumes $\delta(a,b,t)$ then from 10.3 one obtains $e^{i(\delta(a,b,t)+\delta(b,a,t))}=1$ which is not equivalent to 10.4. Right?

Comment: Oh right, my bad. But then $\delta(a,b,t)+\delta(b,a,t) =2 \pi n $

Comment: @Mauricio yes, but this does not imply 10.5 or 10.6,  right?

Comment: I agree there is probably some additional assumption missing, but the example you gave at the beginning does not work either. Also you should probably use $i$ for imaginary in accordance to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first take time out of the picture, because it complicates things. The wavefunction is only defined up to an overall phase anyway; so even if the wavefunction has an *overall phase* $e^{i \delta(a,b)}$, we can get rid of this overall phase by redefining the wavefunction.

The time dependence of the phase of the wavefunction is determined by the Schrodinger equation. For a system of identical particles, the Hamiltonian must be invariant under interchanges of these particles. Therefore if we start in a state where the wavefunction only changes up to a sign, the time evolution of the Schrodinger equation can never introduce a phase which breaks the interchange symmetry. More mathematically, you can introduce an exchange operator $P$ which exchanges $a$ and $b$. This operator commutes with the Hamiltonian, $[H,P]=0$, so a state that starts as an eigenstate of $P$ will remain under time evolution.

In terms of your example, a few points.

- First, a sort of trivial point for this question, but important in general, is that the wavefunction you wrote is not normalizable. This is easy to fix if you replace $|a|^2+|b|^2$ by something like $e^{-|a|^2 - |b|^2}$.
- Second, your example relies on an overall phase $e^{i |a|^2 t}$. At $t=0$, this phase vanishes, and your wavefunction is symmetric under $a\leftrightarrow b$. (Alternatively, we could pick an arbitrary reference time $t_0$, and multiply the wavefunction by an overall phase $e^{-i |a|^2 t_0}$, in accordance with paragraph 1, to get a symmetric wavefunction). Evolving the state from $t$ (or $t_0$, multiplying by $e^{-|a|^2 t_0}$) can never break this symmetry, because the Hamiltonian by assumption is invariant under the interchange of $a$ and $b$.
- I suspect Philips took this to be understood when he said "When this condition **for an acceptable wavefunction** is satisfied" (emphasis mine), but I agree this is a subtlety that's worth making explicit (I had never thought of it in this way before).

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer.  May be it Is  possible to mathematically show that if Hamiltonian is invariant under position variable permutations then the delta in equation 10.3 is independent of position variables.

Comment: @Coniferous I think the statement is that if the initial state is symmetric or antisymmetric under interchange, then the state will remain so. The proof is you can define an exchange operator $P$ which exchanges the particles, and this operator commutes with the Hamiltonian, $[H,P]=0$, so an eigenstate of $P$ remains an eigenstate of $P$ under time evolution. I don't think you can directly prove $\delta$ is independent of $a,b$ because you could always multiply the wavefunction by an arbitrary phase.

Comment: I found in https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/lectures/node94.html a neat derivation. Here the author expands on the permutation operator you mentioned!